Why does $\text{Spec}(R)$ give us something geometric?
I'm fairly new to modern algebraic geometry, but I'm trying to get a solid intuitive grasp on how schemes are defined. I have no problem with going from affine schemes to general schemes, but the idea behind affine schemes is not really digesting.
It looks as if the construction is a magical thing that suddenly lets you define a geometric thing from any unital commutative ring $R$.
If I understand the construction, you begin with a unital commutative ring $R$ and consider $\text{Spec}(R)$ and suddenly there is a geometric object for which the points correspond to the maximal ideals and the prime ideals to some kind of subvarieties? From what I understood, ideally you would only want to consider $\text{MaxSpec}(R)$, but you end up with difficulties regarding functoriality.
There was some discussion about similar ideas in here, but I could not find a really satisfactory example there. Should $\text{Spec}(R)$ be identifiable with some ring of functions/polynomials? A priori $\text{Spec}(R)$ seems not to have any relation to algebraic geometry whatsoever (unless $R$ is a polynomial ring), why couldn't this define some other geometric object such as manifold for example? Is this a special case of some more general phenomena?

I'm assuming you're not satisfied with the usual explanation, which is, roughly: pretend $R$ is the ring of functions on some space, now try to find that space. This analogy does work, with some details needed to exclude pathological points in the manifold case, but it doesn't give much intuition for why we're talking about prime ideals in the first place, or why this reverse-engineering is guaranteed to work for all commutative rings.
Here is an exercise that will give you some intuition: Let $X$ be a Hausdorff space, and consider the lattice $\mathcal{O}$ of open sets of $X$. Give a definition of the points of $X$ that only depends on $\mathcal{O}$.
This isn't so hard, but some technicalities arise when you try to generalize this to an arbitrary $T_0$ topological space with non-closed points. You will find that the correct definition looks an awful lot like the definition of a prime ideal. You may also notice that some spaces gain extra points this way, e.g. the cofinite topology on an infinite set embeds into a space with an extra non-closed point, but the same open sets.
The other important intuition is that the lattice of ideals of a commutative ring is already pretty close to having the structure of a lattice of opens. Namely, $\mathcal{I}(R)$ has arbitrary joins, and the multiplication distributes over these joins. Likewise, $\mathcal{O}(X)$ has arbitrary unions, and binary intersection distributes over them. To make the former look like an actual topology, the main thing we need to enforce is that $I\cdot I = I$, which we can do by restricting to just radical ideals.
Finally, if I have a lattice that looks like a topology, I do have to verify a technical condition to prove that it really is one. It turns out, by general versions of the completeness theorem, that it is enough to show there exists a basis of quasi-compact elements, closed under meets, and that the top element is quasi-compact. It is fairly easy to see that the radicals of principal ideals have this property for any commutative ring.
If you want to see all the details (which you probably don't, but maybe someone does), this was the subject of my Ph.D thesis, where I describe $\operatorname{Spec}$ in a universal way for ring-like algebraic gadgets. In short: if you have a notion of ideals with a multiplicative structure, and the completeness theorem applies, then you're guaranteed to get a topological space out of it. Even if the completeness theorem doesn't apply, you still get a lattice that behaves like a lattice of opens.
